# Removing a class when clicking anywhere outside an element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a first-year BSIT student. Although web development isn't taught (at least not yet) in our program, I am trying to self-learn `HTML`, `CSS`, `JavaScript`, and the list goes on.

So the thing is, I'm trying to make border-bottom animate in both ways using CSS transition. I don't quite get event listeners and its event types yet, so I was hoping I could learn if I asked here. The codes are:

```js
        var inputFieldtrigger = document.getElementById("searchFld");
        var inputFieldtarget = document.getElementById("border-bottom");
        
        inputFieldtrigger.onclick = function(){
            inputFieldtarget.classList.add('searchTransition');
        }

        window.addEventListener('click', function(event){
            if (event.target == inputFieldtrigger){
                inputFieldtarget.classList.remove('searchTransition')
            }
        })
```

```css
div.searchfield{  
    margin:-10px 30px;
    padding:0;
    width:auto;
}
.inputfield {
    padding-top:10px;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 16px;
    color:black;
    text-align:left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width:60%;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid blacsk;
    background:transparent;
}
.inputfield:focus {
    outline:none;
}
.inputfield:focus::placeholder{
    opacity:0%;
}
.borderbtm{
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    width:0px;
    transition: width .25s ease-in-out;
}
.searchTransition {
    width:220px;
}
```

```html
<div class="searchfield">
  <form action="index.html?">
    <input id="searchFld" class="inputfield" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Input product name...">
    <div id="border-bottom" class="borderbtm"></div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I want it to run the reverse transition when I click anywhere outside the input field. I was only able to trigger the onclick transition, but not the reversed.

I would appreciate it if you'd do it in vanilla JS. I am still very unfamiliar with `jQuery`. Thank you!

Comment: oh my god, i didn't expect i'll be able to answer this question by myself. i was certain that i racked my brains on this problem earlier in the morning. anyway, i still don't get why it worked. and i'd appreciate it if someone could explain it for me. here is the link for the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1srfny6t/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use JavaScript for this simple thing.

Using only CSS, we can accomplish this enough.

On the following snippet, I have added two new styles.

`.inputfield:focus + .borderbtm { width: 200px; }` - This will set the width of `#border-bottom` selector when the `input` selector is focused.

`.inputfield:blur + .borderbtm { width: 0px; }` - This will set back the width of `#border-bottom` selector when the `input` selector loses focus. (So the user clicked outside of `input`.)

```css
div.searchfield {
  margin: -10px 30px;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
}

.inputfield {
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 60%;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blacsk;
  background: transparent;
}

.inputfield:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.inputfield:focus::placeholder {
  opacity: 0%;
}

.borderbtm {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 0px;
  transition: width .25s ease-in-out;
}

.inputfield:focus + .borderbtm {
  width: 200px;
}

.inputfield:blur + .borderbtm {
  width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="searchfield">
  <form action="index.html?">
    <input id="searchFld" class="inputfield" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Input product name...">
    <div id="border-bottom" class="borderbtm"></div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: i didn't know it was possible with pure css. i have no idea that you can trigger a click on an element and affect an entirely different element. thank you!

Comment: follow-up question: so i was trying to implement this thing such as when the input field gets clicked "focus", the background of its parent div changes. i have tried .inputfield:focus + .searchfield { background: #e3c342; } but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: you can not select parent div when input focus using css.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `document` instead of a `window` to listen for a click event on the DOM.

Also, you need to check if its `false` then remove class. Currently you are just checking if its `truthy` which means - your `if` condition never `executes`.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
   if (event.target != inputFieldtrigger) {
     inputFieldtarget.classList.remove('searchTransition')
    }
})
```

**Working Demo:** Vanilla JS

```js
var inputFieldtrigger = document.getElementById("searchFld");
var inputFieldtarget = document.getElementById("border-bottom");

inputFieldtrigger.onclick = function() {
  inputFieldtarget.classList.add('searchTransition');
}

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target != inputFieldtrigger) {
    inputFieldtarget.classList.remove('searchTransition')
  }
})
```

```css
div.searchfield {
  margin: -10px 30px;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
}

.inputfield {
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 60%;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blacsk;
  background: transparent;
}

.inputfield:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.inputfield:focus::placeholder {
  opacity: 0%;
}

.borderbtm {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 0px;
  transition: width .25s ease-in-out;
}

.searchTransition {
  width: 220px;
}
```

```html
<div class="searchfield">
  <form action="index.html?">
    <input id="searchFld" class="inputfield" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Input product name...">
    <div id="border-bottom" class="borderbtm"></div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: i could also use the principle of this example in other elements or features that i'd soon experiment with. thank you!